# Formats and end of line characters

Tags: perl

Is there any way to change the end of line character for a perl format?

I need to output a file in DOS format and it looks like write does not obey what is in the $\ variable.

Comment: Wow, somebody actually using [`write`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/write.html) (for [forms](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html))?  Unless you mean [`syswrite`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/syswrite.html), that's pretty rare these days.

Comment: Yep thats the one.  Sad but true.  I know I should use Perl6::Form to create the formats, however the requirements were simple and the politics complex to get the module installed so the format was the easiest way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming you are trying to do this on a non-Windows platform?

You just need a :crlf layer on your filehandle, e.g.:

```
open FOO, "> :crlf", "foo.txt" or die "error: $!";
format FOO=
hi
there
.
write FOO;
```

You can apply layers to existing filehandles using binmode:

```
binmode STDOUT, ":crlf";
```